# Updating my application avoids me to get my old files

Tags: c#, clickonce, updates

I am developing a desktop application using C# winforms. I am creating some files and folders on the directory that my application runs at. I am deploying the application by using the click once approach. My problem is that everytime i update my application it creates a new root folder to run at. And i won't be able to use those files anymore. Any workarounds for that? I am thinkin of creating a folder at "C:\MyCompany\MyApplication" but then it will be easily reachable and breakable. I will be happy to hear any other advises or knowledges that will favor me :)

Comment: See this article, and the Microsoft documentation linked therein: http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=814

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should store the files and folders in the user's `Application Data` folder. You can get the path to this folder with this statement:

```
string appDataPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
```

You should then create a folder in that path for your application and store everything there.

There are of course other solutions, but the point is that you should *not* use the application folder, since this will indeed change everytime you publish, *and* it is bad practice for several other reasons (data backup, etc.).

Comment: @JimMischel Yes indeed, but the point is *not* to use the folder where the executable is, especially since this is a ClickOnce app.